# Derived class should always be singleton

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

I am trying to create a base class with some functionality shared between all derived classes. And all derived classes should be Singletons. Below a pseudo example.

```
class ExtensionSettings
{
    public string GetConfigHtml()
    {
        // creat conifig html for all properties
    }

    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        // save stuff
    }
}

class SettingsA : ExtensionSettings
{
    private static SettingsA instance;
    public static SettingsA Instance {get {return instance ?? (instance = new SettingsA());}}

    public string setting1{get;set;}
    public string setting2{get;set;}
}

class SettingsB : ExtensionSettings
{
    private static SettingsB instance;
    public static SettingsB Instance {get {return instance ?? (instance = new SettingsB());}}

    public string setting1{get;set;}
    public string setting2{get;set;}
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(SettingsA.Instance.setting1);
    System.Console.WriteLine(SettingsB.Instance.setting2);
}
```

Is it possible to move the instancing part to the ExtensionSettings base class?

Comment: No, it wouldn't make sense to do so

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? why do the derived classes have to be singletons?

Comment: Your singleton cannot be safely used from multiple threads.  It's also *more* work to do what you're doing (in addition to being less effective) than to write the solution that *will* safely work from multiple threads of just initializing the field with a new instance.  It's *so* little code that I don't see why you'd want to try to do it in a base class even if you could.  It's a single, very short and simple. line of code to write.

Comment: @AlexM I am trying to create a way to easily build settings html. The GetConfigHtml() function in the ExtensionSettings base class uses reflection to loop through the propperties of the class and build the appropriate HTML. So that is why I have an instance of the derived class. But I don't want to create a new instance of SettingsA everytime I need to acces a property. That is why I made it a singleton.

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis, why not create the base class with a constructor that will take calling class as an argument and / or calling class object instance. Then you can loop through the properties of the child class, in the base class to get the values. I don't know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Servy The reason I am trying to do this in the base class is that, even though it's a simple piece of code, it is the same code every time. And when I add the same piece of code to every derived class it feels like something I should add to the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base class doesn't know about the rest of the object to be instantiated.
basically, when you derive from a base class, the extra logic added in derived class
is hidden from base class. therefore, doing instantiation in the base class is not
possible.